# Do List<List<T>> and List<T> have the same raw-type?

Tags: java, type-erasure, raw-types

I have a class `X` which has the following method:

```
public <T> List<T> g(List<T> l) {…}
```

I Also have a class `Y` which extends class `X` and has the following method:

```
public <T> List<T> g(List<List<T>> l) {…}
```

As I understand after the type erasure process they both have the same raw-type. Why Java does not treat `Y::g` as overriden method of `X::g` and fails to compile the code? what if in `g` we had `ArrayList` instead of `List`?

Comment: IIRC those do have the same raw type, but type erasure is more of a runtime thing, than a compile time thing. If there are no  answers tomorrow, I'll write a proper answer.

Comment: Why should it treat both methods as overriden, when you don't override them? Just because the types will be erased during the compilation doesn't mean they will never be considered.

Comment: Can you provide your full code? This doesnt compile for me. http://ideone.com/bfsDKD

Comment: @k5_ like OP says.

Comment: I get the exact error that you expected when I tried to do what you say (they have the same erasure but don't override each other). Please show your full code. (Assuming you're asking why you don't get this compile error - I see you could read your question two opposite ways - please clarify)

Comment: Type erasure would create bytecode that requires Y::g to override X::g, but the compiler realizes that both methods are not override compatible. So it creates a compile error. Similar to having an overload that creates the same erasure. Not sure what other thing you expected.

Comment: The whole point of generics is to provide compile-time failure when the generic types are incompatible.   That’s why trying to  insert a String into a List<Integer> generates a compile time error, even though the raw List type would happily accept the String at run-time.  Naturally we sang this to apply to method declarations and overrides as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1), `Y.g` overrides `X.g` particularly if `Y.g` is a subsignature of `X.g`.

`Y.g` is a [subsignature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) of `X.g` only if:

- `Y.g` has the same signature as `X.g` that is: `public <T> List<T> g(List<T> l);`
- Or, the signature of `Y.g` is the same as the erasure of the signature of `X.g`:

  thus, `Y.g` could be `public List g(List l)` in this case.

Neither of these conditions are true according to your description, hence an error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are misunderstanding type erasure. The main point of generics in Java is to allow stricter type checking during compilation which still allowing shared code at runtime. To do this, the compiler 'erases' the type during compilation. This matters when you are using reflection to check the type at runtime.

So in your case, the compiler is correctly distinguishing between two different types. The fact that these are treated differently at run time has no effect on their signature.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html for an introduction to the topic or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6 for the formal specification.

Comment: So do you think he does or doesn't get an error at compile time? It sounds like you think he doesn't get an error, when in fact, he does, because both methods have the same signature after type erase.